# SQL Server : sort based on current date for last 6 months

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    Month(gl.CREATEDDATETIME) Month,
    COUNT(CASE 
             WHEN gl.marketcode IN ('059', '017', '032', '013', '014', '042', '004', '025', '020')
                --AND DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, gl.createddatetime), 0) =  '4/1/2017  12:00:00 AM'
                THEN 
                   (CASE 
                       WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, gl.processdate, gl.createddatetime) >= 0 
                          THEN 'total'
                       WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, gl.processdate, gl.createddatetime) >= 4 
                          THEN 'outside SLA'
                    END)
            END) AS 'US Outside SLA' 
FROM 
    GL1025 gl 
JOIN 
    MAINDATA ON gl.id = MAINDATA.chargetransactionid 
WHERE 
    gl.createddatetime >= DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY
    MONTH(gl.CREATEDDATETIME)
ORDER BY
    MONTH(GETDATE())
```

I tried this the answer I am getting is

```
Month  US OutsideSLA
--------------------
  3       25830
 12       20654
  1       17821
  4       20684
  2       23777
 11       16379
```

The answer I am looking is

```
 4       20684
 3       25830
 2       23777
 1       17821
12      20654
11      16379
```

I even tried `desc` and with `Format(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM')`

Can anyone help?  please

Comment: A stick without a lollipop. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You tagged it as MySQL and used MySQL in the title.. little problem MySQL does not support the function GETDATE(); so i think you are using MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be saying:

```
Order by YEAR(go.CREATEDATETIME) DESC, Month(gl.CREATEDDATETIME) DESC
```

instead of

```
Order by Month(GetDate())?
```

`GetDate()`'s month is a constant, so the rows will be in any order that the optimizer chooses.  GetDate() is just returning one date, and not at all what you're trying to do... you're trying to sort by the date on each row, not "now".

Comment: the result is like this 1
2
3
4
11
12

Comment: In that case, add the year and add "Descending" as your sort direction.  I've updated the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has `GROUP BY MONTH(gl.CREATEDDATETIME)`, so end result will have one row per month.

You can't put simple `ORDER BY gl.CREATEDDATETIME DESC`, because you are grouping.

You can't write `ORDER BY YEAR(gl.CREATEDATETIME) DESC, MONTH(gl.CREATEDDATETIME) DESC` as well, because you are not grouping by year.

So, you have two options:

**Group by year and month**

```
SELECT
    ...
GROUP BY
    YEAR(gl.CREATEDDATETIME)
    ,MONTH(gl.CREATEDDATETIME)
ORDER BY
    YEAR(gl.CREATEDDATETIME) DESC
    ,MONTH(gl.CREATEDDATETIME) DESC
```

**Take some date from each month when sorting**

```
SELECT
    ...
GROUP BY
    MONTH(gl.CREATEDDATETIME)
ORDER BY
    MIN(gl.CREATEDDATETIME) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is you didn't explain your output.

you want to divide your resultset into 4 each then arrange each group in desc order.

Is this correct ?

```
declare @t table(Months int,USOutsideSLA bigint)
insert into @t VALUES
( 3 ,25830)
,(12 ,20654)
,( 1 ,17821)
,( 4 ,20684)
,( 2 ,23777)
,(11 ,16379)

;with CTE as
(
select * 

,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by months)rn
from @t
)

select months,USOutsideSLA
,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by months desc)rn1
from CTE where rn<=4
union ALL
select months,USOutsideSLA
,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by months desc)rn1
from CTE where rn>4 and rn<=8
```